# jQuery UI change color does not work properly (RoR application)

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a cart view containing a list of elements that i want to animate the color change.

Each element in the list have either white or gray background depending if it is in an odd/even position in the cart.

When i remove an element in the middle of the list, it slides up and all the element change their colors accordingly since their position has changed.

Here is the code:

```
count = 0;
$(".cart_item").each(function(){
   if ( count % 2 == 0 )
   {
     $(this).delay(count * 1000).removeClass("background_gray",800);
   }
   else
   {
     $(this).delay(count * 1000).addClass("background_gray",800);
   }
   count += 1;
 });
```

Adding the class background_gray is working properly, but removing it with the animation does not work. It gets removed but within one shot.

I have tried to do the following as well, but i got the same effect!

```
$(this).delay(count * 1000).addClass("background_white",800).removeClass("background_gray");
```

jQuery-UI is already included properly.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your direct question but did you know you can style alternate rows just using css, and not bother messing about with javascript?

try this, instead of the javascript

```
<style type="text/css">
  .cart_item:nth-child(even) {background: #ccc}
  .cart_item:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
</style>
```

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Obviously you will still need javascript to remove the li or whatever you're doing.

Comment: Thanks ! +1 for the hint ( although i can not using in that specific case because i want to animate element by element and not in the same time...)

Comment: Do you mean you want to animate the changing color of the backgrounds, with a delay in between each row changing color?  That sounds a bit wacky.